ChangeToken.OnChange broken on Ubuntu?
I wrote some code in a library for a bunch of projects to use, which encapsulates updates based on config file changes. My unit tests overwrite the JSON files being observed to exercise this code. The tests pass 100% of the time on my dev machine and less than 50% of the time on the build server (there are 3 test cases, two of which have never passed, and one which occasionally goes through a period of agreeability).
It's a .Net 7 project, though I tried upgrading to .Net 8 to see if it made a difference, and it did not. I eliminated all of my library code to give a distilled example that exhibits the same behavior, which I've included below. It passes every time when run locally, and the assertion at the end fails on the build server every time.
Here are the other details: I'm running xUnit 2.8.1, my development machine is running macOS 14.5 (and I've also tried in Windows 10), and the builds run on the Bamboo build server in a docker image based on Microsoft's official images (e.g. mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 or 7.0), which run some version of Ubuntu.
As mentioned, I tried upgrading .Net versions, and I've also tried the following debugging steps:

Replacing the file extension with .json
Writing the file updates using a stream instead of the File.WriteAllText() convenience method
Calling File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(configFilePath, DateTime.UtcNow) after updating the file
Inserting and lengthening various delays all over the place
Passing a non-null object as state (my real code does this)
Calling config.GetReloadToken() inside a lambda instead of using a method reference

None of these made a difference.
It's always my last resort to blame the framework, but I need to know since the apps using the library will ultimately run in containers on Linux. Searching around, I found a GitHub issue describing behavior close to what I'm seeing, but it was opened 4 years ago and hasn't been touched in nearly two. Is something in my code wrong or missing, or is this a bug in the runtime?
[Fact]
public void BasicTest()
{
    var configFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
    File.WriteAllText(configFilePath, "{ \"MyValue\": 5 }");

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile(configFilePath, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

    var invokeWasCalled = false;

    _ = ChangeToken.OnChange<object>(
        config.GetReloadToken,
        _ => invokeWasCalled = true,
        null!);

    File.WriteAllText(configFilePath, "{ \"MyValue\": 15 }");

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

    invokeWasCalled.Should().BeTrue();
}


Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)); <-- What happens if you replace this with a non-blocking await Task.Delay( 500 ) ?

@Dai thanks, but doing that (and making the whole test case async, with async File I/O overloads) didn't help. The OnChange method is still not called before the test exits.
